# Let $f:[0,∞)→\Bbb R$ be a bounded, differentiable function such that $f(x)f'(x)≥\cos x$, $∀x≥0$. Show that $f(x)$ does not admit a limit as $x→∞$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> **Problem.** Let $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a bounded, differentiable function such that
>   $$f(x)f'(x)\geq\cos x, \qquad \forall x\geq0.$$
>   Show that $f(x)$ does not admit a limit as $x\to\infty$

I have been stuck on this question for a while and though it makes sense intuitively, I can't figure out a rigorous proof. Please help!

Comment: The inequality involving $\cos x$ needs to be written more clearly , the f o (x) part is not clear. Use MathJax for that purpose. Ok it is clear now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have
\begin{align*}
\int_{y}^{x}\left(\dfrac{1}{2}f(t)^{2}\right)'dt&\geq\int_{y}^{x}\cos tdt\\
f(x)^{2}-f(y)^{2}&\geq 2(\sin x-\sin y).
\end{align*}
We let $y=2n\pi$ and $x=2n\pi+\pi/2$ successively for $n=1,2,...$, we get
\begin{align*}
f(2n\pi+\pi/2)^{2}-f(2n\pi)^{2}\geq 2.
\end{align*}
Assuming that $f(x)\rightarrow L$, then $f(x)^{2}\rightarrow L^{2}$, this will violate the above inequality.

Comment: User2843331.Clever.

Answer (score 1):

Define $F(x):= \frac{1}{2}f(x)^2-\sin x.$ Then $F'(x)=f(x)f'(x)- \cos x \ge 0$ for all $x \ge 0.$

Hence $F$ is increasing. Since $f$ is bounded, $F$ is bounded. Therefore the limit

$$L:=\lim_{x \to \infty}F(x)$$

exists in $ \mathbb R.$ Now assume that $l:=\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)$ exists. Then we would get that

$$ \sin x \to \frac{1}{2}l^2-L$$ as $x \to \infty,$ a contradiction